# Scroll doesn't work in LazyColumn with fixed height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to build the screen which is split vertically into 2 sections:

- vertical list at the top with fixed height (can't make it scrollable)
- horizontal list with button + input at the bottom

The problem is, I can't set this list at the top of the screen as scrollable because I'm getting:

> Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum
> height constraints, which is disallowed.

My code:

```
Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Black)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Column {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Gray)
                    .heightIn(0.dp, 48.dp)
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            ) {
                items(passwords.size) { password ->
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        text = passwords[password]
                    )
                    Divider(color = Color.Black, thickness = 2.dp)
                }
            }
            Spacer(Modifier.height(124.dp))
            Row {
                Column {
                    Button({}) {
                        Text("Add")
                    }
                    Spacer(Modifier.width(16.dp))
                    Input()
                }
                Spacer(Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Column {
                    Button({}) {
                        Text("Remove")
                    }
                    Spacer(Modifier.width(16.dp))
                    Input()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting it because you set `Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)`.
LazyColumn is already scrollable if the total height of items is bigger than its height.